# back up and restore erlang nodes

Tags: erlang, backup, erlang-otp, mnesia, message-passing

I wrote a distributed program using Erlang/OTP. I need a backup for that system in case the machines go down. I do save my statistics about my users using mnesia, but how do I save information which I have in ets and dict in my nodes? I also need to restore links between processes.